# uuid.UUID() silently fails

Tags: python, uuid, unicode-string

I'm trying to convert a unicode object to a UUID with the uuid module. This is the code I'm using:

```
GUID = $unicode
GUID = uuid.UUID( GUID )
print 'should be an UUID object:'
print GUID
```

The problem is that GUID doesn't convert...it just stays the same unicode even after running it through UUID(). Also, no error gets thrown. What is going on here?

Comment: What is meant by `GUID = $unicode`?

Comment: Are you saying that `isinstance(uuid.UUID(GUID_string), uuid.UUID)` is False?

Comment: ``GUID = $unicode`` will fail straight out with a syntax error.

Comment: I just mean substitute $unicode with a unicode object like "cf26d50f-08d5-11e2-b6d7-001b639a15a0"

Comment: You accepted an answer but never explained what about your problem was unique to you/your environment.  Please share.

Comment: Should I share here or in the answers comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I gather, your problem is that you get the UUID as a string. This is because you are using `print`, which runs `str()` on an object. Try `print(repr(some_uuid))`.

```
>>> some_uuid = uuid.UUID("3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301")
>>> print(some_uuid)
3f2504e0-4f89-11d3-9a0c-0305e82c3301
>>> print(repr(some_uuid))
UUID('3f2504e0-4f89-11d3-9a0c-0305e82c3301')
```

Your assertion that `isinstance()` returns `False` isn't reproducible on my end:

```
>>> isinstance(uuid.UUID("3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301"), uuid.UUID)
True
```